# Multilingualism website display Post by language or default

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, translate

I am programming a Multilingualism website with symfony
my article table:

| id | original_id | rubrique_id | status | lang | updated_at | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | en | 2021-02-16 00:01:00 | pede libero En |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | fr | 2021-02-16 00:02:00 | pede libero Fr |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | * | 2021-02-16 00:03:00 | pede libero All |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | fr | 2021-02-16 00:04:00 | rhoncus aliquet Fr |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 1 | * | 2021-02-16 00:05:00 | rhoncus aliquet All |

the table also contains other field and relation with table section

I would like to display an article according to the language "en" if not if found no language "en" then display "*"

I tried :

```
SELECT a 
FROM App\Entity\Article 
WHERE (a.lang = 'en' OR a.lang = '*') 
GROUP BY a.original
ORDER BY a.updatedAt DESC
```

according to the solution of Mr. @eshirvana

Query :

```
SELECT p, r FROM App\Entity\Article 
p INNER JOIN p.rubrique r 
WHERE (p.lang = :value_0 OR p.lang = :value_1) 
AND p.status = :stat AND r.status = :rstat 
GROUP BY p.original 
ORDER BY p.updatedAt DESC, p.lang DESC
```

it always shows me the last add

I improved solution two proposed by Mr. @eshirvana

## Solution

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` as post
WHERE status = 1
AND (
    post.lang = 'en' 
    OR (
      NOT(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `articles` as subpost 
                 WHERE subpost.lang = 'en' 
                 AND  subpost.status = 1 
                 AND subpost.original_id = post.original_id))
      AND post.lang = '*'
    )
) 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

thank you for any proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you return only one record each time and always you return '*' if you can't find your desired lang, one way is :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM App\Entity\Article a
WHERE a.lang  IN ( 'es', '*')
GROUP BY a.original
ORDER by a.lang DESC , a.updatedAt DESC
```

but bullet proof way is to :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE (lang = 'fr' 
       OR (
           not exists(select 1 FROM `articles` WHERE lang = 'fr') 
           and lang = '*'
          ) 
       )
GROUP BY original_id
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i have another "updated_At" field so i already use "ORDER BY p.updatedAt DESC" unless i can use two ORDER BY

Comment: @Redwan - maybe you can , edit your question and show us the whole query

Comment: then yes you can combine two columns in order by statement , see my updated asnwer

Comment: I modified the post, look at Full doctrine getQuery ().
always the same result

Comment: @Redwan what about it , 1)  you need to add top 1 after select 2) order of columns in order by statement matters `ORDER by a.lang DESC , a.updatedAt DESC`

Comment: I tried "ORDER by a.lang DESC, a.updatedAt DESC" it displays by language and in addition if it displays language "*" even if the language 'fr' exists

Comment: the second solution, you know how to do it with doctrine ?

Comment: I modified the post to add the doctrine version

Comment: first one should work , unless you have something else instead of * , and no I'm not familiar with php frameworks

Comment: I use '*' as the default language, thank you for your help but it always shows me the first add

Comment: Solution number two it does not display default language, if the given language does not exist